# Find the F-statistic value for ANOVA first linear model

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, statsmodels

I am going through stats with python topics. I am struck with one hands on.

Problem statement:

> Perform ANOVA on the first linear model obtained while working with mtcars data set.
>   **Display the F-statistic value**.

What i did for the problem statement:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm    
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf    
from statsmodels.stats import anova

mtcars_data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars").data    
print(mtcars_data.columns)

mt_model1 = smf.ols('mpg ~ cyl', mtcars_data ).fit()    
print(anova.anova_lm(mt_model1))
```

[image: output]

How can I display the *F*-statistic for the above problem?

Comment: Please do not post a screenshot of the output if it is just text. Type/copy the output text into the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to get the F Statistic value from the anova table for cyl attribute , so something like this

```
print(anova.anova_lm(mt_model1).F["cyl"])
```

Comment: I have tried with your code even the testcase failed for the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already fit the model with the desired variables in mt_model1, you can directly call for F-statistic by,

```
print(mt_model1.fvalue)
```

This can be also used when you have multiple predictors in your model.

Comment: I have the tried the above line but still thetest case for the problem is failed

Comment: Not clear the problem as you are asking a way to display F-statistics. However, if you need to run ANOVA with more details than your output, you can try, print(mt_model1.summary())

Comment: problem statement is Perform ANOVA on the first linear model obtained while working with mtcars data set and Display the F-statistic value. 'mtcars' is a data set, Use the data set to generate anova model and display the F-statistic value.

Answer (score 1):

After many trials got this.

```
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

    mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars').data

    lm = ols('mpg ~ wt', mtcars).fit()
    av = sm.stats.anova_lm(lm,type=2)
    print(av.F.wt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code which worked for me and I passed handon.
I think they asked for F-statics value of wt variable only and last print statement gives that in output file.

```
#Write your code here
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.stats import anova

mtcars_data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars").data
#mt_model1 = smf.ols('mpg ~ cyl', mtcars_data ).fit()

#print(mt_model1.fvalue)

lm = smf.ols('mpg ~ wt', mtcars_data).fit()
av = sm.stats.anova_lm(lm)
print(av.F.wt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to above if you are looking for log value based model fit,
You need to fit model with Log and below code works.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.stats import anova
import numpy as np

mtcars_data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars").data
#mt_model1 = smf.ols('mpg ~ cyl', mtcars_data ).fit()

#print(mt_model1.fvalue)

lm = smf.ols('np.log(mpg) ~ np.log(wt)', mtcars_data).fit()
av = sm.stats.anova_lm(lm)
print(av.F['np.log(wt)'])
```